# ajax data json using web method returns undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, webmethod

I have an asp.net web page, using html controls. I want to save appointment to database, by sending input values codebehind using web method and I want page not to refresh. So I used Ajax.
in Ajax, succeed function fails and returns undefined.

default.aspx:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="hName" name="hName" type="text" />
    <input id="hSurname" name="hSurname" type="text" />
    <input id="hPhone" name="hPhone" type="text" />
    <input id="rNote" name="rNote" type="text" />
    <select id="rTypeSelect">
                  <option value="1">A</option>
                  <option value="2">B</option>
                  <option value="3">C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSaveAppointment" name="btnSaveAppointment"/>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#btnSaveAppointment").live('click', function (event) {

        name = $('#hName').val();
        surname = $('#hSurname').val();
        phone = $('#hPhone').val();
        note = $('#rNote').val();
        type = $("#rTypeSelect option:selected").text();
        rdate = '01.09.2015';
        rhour = '09.30';
        var appointment= {};
        appointment= {
            _name: name, 
            _surname: surname,
            _phone: phone,
            _note: note,
            _type: type,
            _rdate: rdate,
            _rhour: rhour
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../saveAppointment.aspx/save',
            data: { appointment: JSON.stringify(appointment) },

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,

            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error!' + result.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

saveAppointment.aspx web method:

```
public partial class saveAppointment : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string save(string jsondata)
        {
            var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Appointment>(jsondata);
            Appointment r = (Appointment)output;
            r.Name= output.rName.ToString();
            //sql code here     
            return r.Name;
        }
```

and this is the class:

```
public class Appointment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string rName{ get; set; }
        public string rSurname { get; set; }
        public string rPhone{ get; set; }
        public string rNote{ get; set; }
        public string rType{ get; set; }
        public DateTime rDate{ get; set; }
        public DateTime rHour{ get; set; }
    }
```

When I remove WebMethod's parameter (string jsondata), Ajax success function doesn't fail. But when I put json parameter, it fails. Please show me where I am doing wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../saveAppointment.aspx/save',
            data: "{ 'appointment': "+JSON.stringify(appointment)+" }",//use inverted commas here

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,

            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error!' + result.d);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what you've changed exactly so it can benefit future readers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have got confused on what type of object you are using in C#-land. 'output' is of type Appointment and therefore its member would be called _name not rName. If you inspect the value of r (from the line Appointment r = (Appointment)output;) then it will all become clear, I think.

Following on from your comment - there is no way for the system to know that _name maps to rName. You can change their names to match or you can do something like:

```
public class Appointment
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_name")]
    public string rName{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I cast jsondata (output) to Appointment object type, after deserialization. So r is Appointments instance here. rName is what refers Name in the Appointment class.

Comment: you are right. class must match with json, and i added also JsonProperty annotations. but the issue is still the same it must be something else.. thank you anyway.

Comment: Any chance you can up-vote me - I need cred so I can comment on a posts rather than having to post answers :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
parameter pass appointment not jsondata in severside code

        public static string save(string appointment)
        {
            var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Appointment>(appointment);
            Appointment r = (Appointment)output;
            r.Name= output.rName.ToString();
            //sql code here     
            return r.Name;
        }
```